# How can I export ENV variables of a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker

[image]

I use `docker inspect <container>` to inspect the information of a container and find that the `ENV` variables won't be export when I execute `docker export <container> > <file>`. This would cause many problems when someone passes the exported file to another host machine since the `ENV` variables are lost. Could anyone can help me to figure out how to export the `ENV` variables when I use `docker export`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to share Docker content between multiple hosts you would generally create a Docker image and share that (and an image can include environment variables). The `docker export` command is strictly for exporting the contents of a container filesystem as a tar archive and provides neither environment variables nor any other container or image metadata.

Comment: More concisely: I wouldn't try to `docker export` a container at all; `docker run` a new container on the other machine instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need docker export for this.

Use `jq` utility to get the environment variables via `docker container inspect` command.

```sh
docker container inspect containerID | jq -r '.[].Config.Env[]' > containerID_ENVfile
```

Above will get you the list of environment variables present in the docker container and will export it to a file. You can have your own filename.